# Redirect 301 with condtion

Tags: .htaccess

I can redirect all traffic to new blog subdirectory like:

```
Redirect 301 / https://new-website.com/blog/
```

However, I want this redirect to happen ONLY if it comes from old website subdomain referral:

```
https://blog.old-website.com
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mod-rewrite`

```
RewriteEngine on


RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^https://blog\.oldsite\.com
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://newsite.com/blog%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

Comment: thanks, but it did not work, here is how it looks: https://gist.github.com/hopewise/9e9ca25c5d5a9a809fb9e3b6dc05659b

Comment: isn't there supposed to be a space between `^https://` ? so, `^ https://` ? I might be wrong, but when I test it with the space, it works, without, the `RewriteCond` doesn't work.

Comment: @joe there is no space. I am not sure how it worked with a space because `^ https://` isn't a valid referer string. Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: You 100% know better than me mate, I wasn't challenging, just checking :) - I tested it on that .htaccess tester site.

Comment: @joe Test it on your real Web server.

Comment: But why it doesn't work for me? Did you see my implementation at my gist? (at first comment)

Comment: @simo I think your other rules are overriding this . Try placing this at the top of your htaccess before your other rules .

Comment: Thanks, I tried to place them at the top of htaccess, before any other rules, but still did not work..